# Tool to Migrate TFS2015 on-premises XML to ADO Server 2019 on-premises inherited?

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

My company wants to migrate TFS2015 on-premises XML projects w/ custom fields to Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-premises inherited projects, so they can use all the features the inheritance type has to offer. They'll want to maintain work item history and links to other work items. Links to TFVC changesets is also wanted if possible, but it's not a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You are better upgrading the collection to Azure DevOps Server 2019. This should be available on the latest version of Azure DevOps Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/upgrade-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2019

**Option 2:**

If that is not available in the server version then the only way to get parity would be to upgrade, then move to Azure DevOps Services, where it is available.

**Option 3:**

You can create a new inherited Project and migrate all of the work items with history, and use Git-TFS to convert your TFVC to Git. You can then use the migration mapping file of TFVC ID to Git Commit to map the commit links when you migrate the work items.

**Option 4:**

You can create a new inherited Project and migrate all of the work items with history, but leave the TFVC code in the old Project. This creates a very disjointed experience for users and some of the features don't really work well across the Project boundary.

**Final**

I have ordered these options by my preference if it was my project!